# LUIS not identifying day-of-week anymore

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Today my LUIS app stopped recognizing day-of-week references as builtin.datetime.date entities. Previously, when I gave the bot an utterance of "Tuesday at 2PM" for example, LUIS will send through a builtin.datetime.date component (Tuesday) and a builtin.datetime.time component (2PM).
Now the date component (Tuesday) also comes through as a builtin.datetime.time.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Pieter

Comment: Hi Pieter, I'm not sure why it's now being recognized as `builtin.datetime.time`. Is this only affecting days of the week? For example in the utterance "4/25 at 2PM", does this return a `builtin.datetime.date` and `builtin.datetime.time`? Or does it return two `builtin.datetine.time` entities?

Comment: Hi Steven, this issue resolved itself. I have encountered it once before as well, but it also resolved itself. If I run into it again, then I'll check your recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it works now! :)

Comment: Hi Steven, this issue appeared again today. When passing in an actual date as per your recommendation, LUIS passes it through correctly. Also, if specifying a day only, for example 'friday', with no time component, then LUIS identifies it correctly as a builtin.datetime.date.

Comment: Hi Pieter, work is underway on improving the datetime recognition. The improvements should be released in the near future.